# Missing file `mysql2-0.2.7` in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, mysql2

I got interested in Ruby on Rails a few weeks ago.  I am running on a MacBook Pro with OS 10.6.

```
Ruby version 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.6.0]
Rails version 3.0.5
gem version 1.7.1 
MySQL Version 5.5.10, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1.
```

I have a migration ready to go, however, when I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
Could not find mysql2-0.2.7 in any of the sources
```

I have run `sudo gem install mysql2` and it completes successfully. The missing "package" is installed in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7`.  Any ideas all?

Comment: Have you made sure that your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are up to date and include mysql2?

Comment: Please add the output of `gem env` to your question. Also, what does `gem search mysql` show?

Comment: try running `bundle install` in your project dir

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "mysql2" to "mysql" or vise versa in database.yml

Answer (score 0):

Note : I have performed below steps on my Linux machine , so please use the `commands` equivalent to your `mac os` for `apt-get` etc .

Just follow the steps below and you will be able to solve your error :

Install mysql-server using command :

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`

After that , just run below commands in your terminal :

1. `sudo service mysql stop`
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload`
3. `sudo service mysql start`

Now , run the command `mysql -u root -p` , you will successfully enter into the `mysql` command prompt.

I hope this helps. :)